# Trying to shoot bullets

Tags: c#, .net, math, xna

So, i'm making my own game of asteroids and i'm a bit stuck. I have a bullet that is fired from the ship when i press the key Z. But the bullet always fires off in the same direction and i'm not sure how to change that? I want it to fire off in the direction which the ship is facing. Also, if i push Z quickly (to fire many bullets) the one bullet appears to keep getting reset. How do i fix these issues? Here is my code:

```
class SpaceShip
{
    private Vector2 pos; //Our position in 2D.
    private Texture2D tex; //Our texture
    private float speed = 8; //The speed to move.
    private float angleOfRotation = 0;
    Sprite tempSprite;


    public SpaceShip(Vector2 pos, Texture2D tex, Texture2D bulletsToAdd)
    {
        this.pos = pos; //Our starting position
        this.tex = tex; //Our texture
        tempSprite = new Sprite(bulletsToAdd); 
    }



    private void WorldWrap(int worldWidth, int worldHeight)
    {

        if (this.pos.X < 0)
        {
            //If we've past the left side of the window, set on other side of the world.
            this.pos.X = worldWidth;
        }
        if (this.pos.X > worldWidth)
        {
            //If we've past the right side of the window, set on other side of the world.
            this.pos.X = this.tex.Width;
        }
        if (this.pos.Y < 0)
        {
            //If we've passed the top side of the window, set on other side of the world.
            this.pos.Y = worldHeight;
        }
        if (this.pos.Y > worldHeight)
        {
            //If we've passed the bottom side of the window, set on other side of the world.
            this.pos.Y = this.tex.Height;
        }
    }

    public void CreateBullets(Texture2D bulletsToAdd)
    {

        tempSprite.Position = new Vector2((pos.X),(pos.Y));
        tempSprite.Velocity = new Vector2((float)7, 7);
        //tempSprite.Rotation = angleOfRotation;
    }


    public void Update(int WorldWidth, int WorldHeight, Texture2D bulletsToAdd)
    {
        KeyboardState keys = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            //We want to turn the ship LEFT
            this.angleOfRotation -= 2f;

        }
        if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            //We want to turn the ship RIGHT
            this.angleOfRotation += 2f;

        }
        if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            //We're pressing the up key (W) so go Forwards!
            this.pos.X += (float)(Math.Cos(this.angleOfRotation * Math.PI / 180) * this.speed);
            this.pos.Y += (float)(Math.Sin(this.angleOfRotation * Math.PI / 180) * this.speed);

        }
        if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        {
            //We're pressing the down key (S) so go Backwards!
            this.pos.X -= (float)(Math.Cos(this.angleOfRotation * Math.PI / 180) * this.speed);
            this.pos.Y -= (float)(Math.Sin(this.angleOfRotation * Math.PI / 180) * this.speed);

        }
        if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            //We're pressing the up key (W) so go Forwards!
            this.pos.X += (float)(Math.Cos(this.angleOfRotation * Math.PI / 180) * this.speed);
            this.pos.Y += (float)(Math.Sin(this.angleOfRotation * Math.PI / 180) * this.speed);

        }
        if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        {
            //We're pressing the down key (S) so go Backwards!
            this.pos.X -= (float)(Math.Cos(this.angleOfRotation * Math.PI / 180) * this.speed);
            this.pos.Y -= (float)(Math.Sin(this.angleOfRotation * Math.PI / 180) * this.speed);

        }

        if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            //We want to turn the ship LEFT. Rotate it counter-clockwise
            this.angleOfRotation -= 2f;

        }
        if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        {
            //We want to turn the ship RIGHT. Rotate it clockwise
            this.angleOfRotation += 2f;

        }
        if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Z))
        {

            CreateBullets(bulletsToAdd); 
        }


        tempSprite.Position += tempSprite.Velocity;

        //check if we need to move the ship.
        WorldWrap(WorldWidth, WorldHeight);

    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch batch)
    {
        batch.Draw(this.tex, //Texture to use.
        this.pos, //Position to draw at
        new Rectangle(0, 0, this.tex.Width, this.tex.Height),Color.White, (float)((this.angleOfRotation + 90) * Math.PI / 180), new Vector2(this.tex.Width / 2, this.tex.Height / 2), 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);

        batch.Draw(tempSprite.Texture, tempSprite.Position, null, Color.White, tempSprite.Rotation, tempSprite.Center, tempSprite.Scale, SpriteEffects.None, 1.0f);
    } //End Draw function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you only have a single bullet - `tempSprite`. You're probably going to want to create a separate `Bullet` class and a `List<Bullet>` somewhere that you can add bullets to.

All you need for this is a little trigonometry. Right now your velocity vector is a constant <7, 7>. What you want to do is make that vector go in the direction the spaceship is pointing at. So assuming your angle is in radians and not degrees (if they're in degrees you'll want to change them to radians), we can use `Math.Sin()` and `Math.Cos()` to get the individual X and Y components of the velocity vector like this:

```
bulletSpeed = 7;
tempSprite.Velocity = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(angleOfRotation) * bulletSpeed, (float)Math.Sin(angleOfRotation) * bulletSpeed);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I think i'll make a separate class. Having a list of bullets would be good. I guess i'm just confused as to how i would capture the number of times the user presses "Z" ... if i put it in a list, the list will contain old and new presses. Not sure how to differentiate between them. Would i just clear the list? and some point? How would i know which point to do this at though?

Comment: In your main update method, you could iterate through the bullet list and remove all bullets that are offscreen or add an update method to `Bullet` that keeps track of how long it's been since it was created and delete the bullets that have been around for more than x seconds. Each Z press creates a bullet that's added to the list, there's no need to track which one is which, you just need to have some condition that removes bullets.

Comment: You can also consider using a Pool instead of a List, to prevent memory allocation and garbage collection.

Comment: What Jon said.  Seriously - use a Pool<Bullet>. [If you don't have a Pool<Bullet>, write one :)] If you continually add/remove new instances of Bullet to/from your collection, GC is going to come along and completely ruin everything. (+1 Jon)